# ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) on win10

Tags: mysql

I had MySQL 8.0 installed on my win 10 system. I had added "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin" into the Path variable. When I execute "mysql" in a cmd terminal,I got "ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)". I manually restarted the MYSQL80 service with service.msc, but failed again. Please help me. Thanks a lot!

[image]

[image]

Comment: lookslike mariadb service is not running,not listen on localhost or do notuse the standard port

Comment: I use MySql 8.0 instead of MariaDB.

Comment: How could I change the port?